# SQL Server and Visual Studio: how to cope with different Microsoft.SqlServer.Types versions

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

In Visual Studio (2019) I've made an assembly that is using Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, and I compiled it without error messages.
Now I try to import this assembly into my SQL Server (2019) database with T-SQL, but this message appears:

> ***Msg 10300, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Assembly "MyAssembly" references assembly 'microsoft.sqlserver.types, version=15.100.0.0,
> culture=neutral, publickeytoken=89845dcd8080cc91.', which is not
> present in the current database. SQL Server attempted to locate and
> automatically load the referenced assembly from the same location
> where referring assembly came from, but that operation has failed
> (reason: another assembly with same SQL name is already present in the
> current database). Please load the referenced assembly into the
> current database and retry your request.***

In SSMS (18.5.1) I see that the microsoft.sqlserver.types that SQL Server is using has a different version: 15.0.0.0.
If I try to remove this from SQL Server before importing the 15.100.0.0 version I get a message saying that deleting is not possible because it is a system assembly.

What is the best I can do now? I am brand new to this stuff.

Comment: Have you tried a binding redirect?

Comment: I replaced the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types used by Visual Studio by the one SQL Server is using. Problem gone!